# CGSSetWindowWarp not working in 64 bits apps

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am developping a Mac OS X app using the undocummented CGSSetWindowWarp function.
Everything is ok when compiing in 32 bits but it stop to work (window dissapear completly) when compiling in 64 bits.
Do you have any idée where the issue can be?

Thanks in advance for your help

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about the function signature? The size of the parameters might have changed / might not have changed but int needs to be short, etc.

Or they might have stopped supporting that function altogether.

Comment: This function is used by the dock for the "genie" minimizing effect but you're right, maybe something has changed. What is strange is that in 32 bits it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The points in the warp mesh are not actually `CGPoints`, they use `float` for `x` and `y` even in 64-bit. (`CGPoint` uses `double` on 64-bit)

You can redefine the warp mesh and function like this:

```
typedef struct CGSPoint {
    float x;
    float y;
} CGSPoint;

typedef struct {
    CGSPoint local; 
    CGSPoint global;
} CGSPointWarp;

extern CGError CGSSetWindowWarp(CGSConnectionID conn, CGSWindowID window, int w, int h, CGSPointWarp **mesh)
```